# Trying to understanding a for loop that iterates through 40 bits

Tags: c++, arduino, bit

I recently ordered a DHT22 temperature and humidity sensor to play around with as well as some arduino nanos that I am still waiting on, and I was reading up on a few tutorials and things I am going to do with them when I get them and was reading through how to use the DHT22 which was pretty simple, and after reading the data sheet was interested in how they iterate through the 40 bits of data as I have never played around with bytes in code before so looked up the library for it which is here https://github.com/markruys/arduino-DHT.

Datasheet for DHT22 is here https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/Digital+humidity+and+temperature+sensor+AM2302.pdf

This is the main block of code that loops through the bits.

This is what I think is happening; you have an 8 bit int of i that starts at -3 because it uses 3 bits to start communicating with the sensor. i < 2 * 40 keeps i below 2 but iterates through 40 times (this is a stab in the dark, i haven't seen it before).

Next is the bit I'm not quite understanding at all, the while loop, where if the pin is high - 1 and is == (i(i being 0) & 1) then the while loop will be LOW, or if i is 1 then the loop will be high. Which then flows into the if statement where if ( i >= 0 && (i & 1)), but won't i eventually always be 1? If not what is modifying i? From what I have looked at you don't want to move the bits when the signal is LOW?

I can see what the rest of the code is doing I'm just not understanding it, the first if statement moves the bits i data left through every loop and if the signal is high for > 30 micro secs then the bit is 1 and a 1 is added to data.

```c
// We're going to read 83 edges:
// - First a FALLING, RISING, and FALLING edge for the start bit
// - Then 40 bits: RISING and then a FALLING edge per bit
// To keep our code simple, we accept any HIGH or LOW reading if it's max 85 usecs long

uint16_t rawHumidity = 0;  
uint16_t rawTemperature = 0;  
uint16_t data = 0;

for ( int8_t i = -3 ; i < 2 * 40; i++ ) {
  byte age;
  startTime = micros();
  do {
    age = (unsigned long)(micros() - startTime);
    if ( age > 90 ) {
      error = ERROR_TIMEOUT;
      return;
    }
  } while ( digitalRead(pin) == (i & 1) ? HIGH : LOW );

  if ( i >= 0 && (i & 1) ) {
    // Now we are being fed our 40 bits
    data <<= 1;

    // A zero max 30 usecs, a one at least 68 usecs.
    if ( age > 30 ) {
      data |= 1; // we got a one
    }
  }

  switch ( i ) {
    case 31:
      rawHumidity = data;
      break;
    case 63:
      rawTemperature = data;
      data = 0;
      break;
  }
}

// Verify checksum

if ( (byte)(((byte)rawHumidity) + (rawHumidity >> 8) + ((byte)rawTemperature) + (rawTemperature >> 8)) != data ) {
  error = ERROR_CHECKSUM;
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> This is what I think is happening; you have an 8 bit int of i that starts at -3 because 
>   it uses 3 bits to start communicating with the sensor. i < 2 * 40 keeps i below 2 but 
>   iterates through 40 times (this is a stab in the dark, i haven't seen it before)

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

`*` (as the multiplication operator) has higher precedence than `<` (as less-than), so the terms are grouped such that `*` is resolved first.

So (i < 2 * 40)  gets resolved (i < (2 * 40)).  It's equivalent to (i < 80).

> Next is the bit I'm not quite understanding at all, the while loop, where if the pin 
>   is high - 1 and is == (i(i being 0) & 1) then the while loop will be LOW, or if i is 
>   1 then the loop will be high.

```
do { 
...
}
while ( digitalRead(pin) == (i & 1) ? HIGH : LOW );
```

Here, `==` has the higher precedence, so `(digitalRead(pin) == (i & 1)` is resolved first.  ie, true when either `digitalRead(pin)` is 0 and `i` is even, `digitalRead(pin)` is 1 and `i` is odd.  *[since (i & 1) effectively tests the lowest bit]*
Then the ternary subexpression is resolved, returning HIGH if true and LOW if false.

Have to run, hopefully that gets you there.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I’m getting it now. For whatever reason i thought you could only & 1’s or 0’s. Just to confirm the data bits shift left only when the while loop is HIGH?

Comment: apparently I'm too wordy for the inline reply: see other answer

Answer (score 0):

```
// We're going to read 83 edges:
// - First a FALLING, RISING, and FALLING edge for the start bit
// - Then 40 bits: RISING and then a FALLING edge per bit
```

The data bits shift left when the 'while' loop breaks: that happens when
the conditional's ternary operator result *(HIGH or LOW)* evaluates false.  It's somewhat unclear exactly when that should occur since we lack definitions for HIGH and LOW.

However, since:

- all-caps identifiers generally indicate that the identifier represents a macro,
- HIGH and LOW having strictly constant truth value would make having the ternary expression in there at all totally pointless *(if true then true else false??)*,
- *something* in all this supposedly distinguishes rising-edge values from falling edges,
- there's pretty much no other sensible place for that to happen (unless the pin read function does it internally and the comments discussion is just watercooler stuff)

...we should probably assume they each expand to an expression of some sort, and the result of THAT determines whether the loop should stop.

So, most likely, `data <<= 1;` occurs when:

- `digitalRead(pin)` is high and `*~something~*`
- `digitalRead(pin)` is low and `*~something else~*`

From what I can see, it would make the most sense if *~something~* and *~something else~* depend on the value of `age`.